# Object getting wrong time stamp from Hibernate saved to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datetime

I am new to Hibernate and working on a web project that uses it.

I have an object called area that has a date object(`java.sql.Timestamp`) attribute modifiedDate. When I create a new object modifieDate is null and after send it down to `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(area);` in my own class that extends `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport` it is set with current  timestamp and saved in the database. In the database it is saved as a `datetime`.

My problem is most of the time the object is updated with a Date that is 1 millisecond off compared to what it is saved as in the database, this leads to this exception 
if anything is attempted updated without reloading the page:

```
an org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

There are no problems with the correct date when getting the object from database subsequent, it is only at creation it gets the wrong value.

Is there a way to get the correct modifiedDate at SaveOrUpdate?

Incase it is needed the mapping uses `<timestamp name="modifiedDate" column="ModifiedDate"/>` and all test are run on localhost with everything running on the same machine.

I already have a work around, by calling `getHibernateTemplate().refresh(area);` right after the saveOrUpdate I get the right timestamp, but I would still like to know if there is a way to get the correct modifiedDate at saveOrUpdate.

Comment: Maybe it is rounding the nanoseconds to one millisecond more?

Comment: @Luciano That is a very good possibility, but how do i fix that and why does it not do the same rounding error everywhere?

Comment: If you want to try, use Timestamp.setNanos(0); in your modifiedDate field. I don't know what flavor of DB you are using, but if that datetime column has millisecond precision, I think you should change modifiedDate from Timestamp to java.util.Date

Comment: When stepping through I just had one where time stamp ended in .945 and in the db it ended in .947.
So not so sure if it is a rounding error, went with the easy solution for now that once the object has been saved I throw it out and get a new one from database. But would still like to know why this happens.

Comment: @PaulMorie MSSQL, I want to say 2008 R2 but I don't have it right here.

Comment: See ny answer; datetime on SQL Server rounds millisecond values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My theory:

What's happening is that you're using a less precise data type on the database side than on the Java side, so the values you persist to the DB are losing precision (or rounded somehow, see below) during generation of the DB-specific SQL.  Here's how to tell for sure:

1. Remember, Hibernate works by generating SQL statements that are executed in your database.  In order to diagnose issues with Hibernate mappings like this, you will need to see the SQL being executed in order to know precisely what's going on.
2. Turn on the ['show SQL'](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-logging) setting for Hibernate.  This will cause Hibernate to dump the raw SQL being executed on the database.
3. Examine the logs from your tests.  It will help to implement `toString` on your class and log the value to compare against the SQL hibernate generates for an `INSERT`.  Do the values in the SQL statements match the value of the Java timestamp field?

You should check the precision settings for your database's `DATETIME` type.  For example, on SQL Server, `DATETIME` implements [millisecond rounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819) (see 'accuracy' field) that effectively causes loss of precision for millisecond values.  You will want to change the Java type your column is mapped to or change the type of the column in the database, depending on your precision needs.

Comment: I had a similar issue and your precision remark saved my day. I was working with SQL Server and I didn't specify which dialect to use. It seems that Hibernate picked up the 2005 dialect and created DATETIME columns for my java Date objects. I was getting StaleObjectStateExceptions when creating a record, which was pretty frustrating. After switching the dialect to 2008+ and changing all columns from DATETIME to DATETIME2, the problem went away. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, Andre!